# iOS in app purchase issue

Tags: ios, transactions, in-app-purchase

I have an app on Appstore containing in app purchase. Now I want to know:

1. How can I view what in app items were purchased.
2. If any user did transaction then from where I can get that full transaction detail.
3. In addition, in case, if any user made a claim of in app purchase and credits not returned to user or showed in application then how to verify that claim or what information can help to verify the claim?

Please provide all detail, the more information more better appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Bhai code likh du toh clega kya...:p

Comment: Likh de bhai @Ghanshyam

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SKPaymentQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/). It helps you to know / make purchases.

By calling `addTransactionObserver:` and subscribing to `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocol you tell `SKPaymentQueue` that you want to kwon when things are happened.

[SKPaymentTransactionObserver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/) have methods that called when user buy / cancel / restore purchases.

For example:

```
public func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for transaction in transactions as! [SKPaymentTransaction] {
      switch (transaction.transactionState) {
      case .Purchased:
        // everything is ok
        break
      case .Failed:
        // something fail
        break
      case .Restored:
        // purchase restored
        break
      case .Deferred:
        break
      case .Purchasing:
        break
      }
    }
}
```

[There is](http://www.raywenderlich.com/105365/in-app-purchases-tutorial-getting-started) a great tutorial from Ray.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help but this wasn't i was asking for. I was asking when we have to make sure when any user purchased any product from app and didn't received and later he ask for refund or something then how we can verify that if the user is right or wrong.

Comment: Do you have in-app purchase hosted content?

Comment: Hosted? I don't get it, or you mean to say like we have done in our app that we save a record of purchase on server database for the sake of confirmation and record for future? Is that the same thing you are asking for?

Comment: @AkshaySunderwani, no, I mean content that you can keep on Apple servers. So I guess you haven't. I didn't understand you. You can not accept/decline user's refunds. You can check if item is purchased and show/hide content in you app.

Comment: What type of content? Like i checked at my iTunes account it shows the list of in-app items and there purchase date, time, location but there is no such information which can help me to verify that if user claim for purchase was right or wrong? @rkyr